# How to create a User Defined Function for SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a fairly large stored procedure that I'm trying to simplify for readability.

It contains many union clauses with statements like the one shown below:

**Fig.1**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
        FROM (
          SELECT Id 
            FROM OrderLineItems 
            WHERE Orders.Id = Order_Id) AS Sub
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
              FROM NormalizedLineItems 
              WHERE (Sub.Id = OrderLineItem_Id)
                AND (OutOfStock = 1))))
    AND (EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 AS Total
        FROM OrderShipments 
        WHERE (Orders.Id = Order_Id)
          AND (CarrierApproved = 0)))
    AND (IsQuote = 0)
    AND (Cancelled = 0)
    AND (Archived = 0)
    AND (Completed = 0)
    AND (Holding = 0)
```

However there are many reoccurring patterns in each statement.

The following pattern turns up several times Fig.2

**Fig.2**

```
  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
        FROM (
          SELECT Id 
            FROM OrderLineItems 
            WHERE Orders.Id = Order_Id) AS Sub
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
              FROM NormalizedLineItems 
              WHERE (Sub.Id = OrderLineItem_Id)
                AND (OutOfStock = 1))))
```

I'm trying to (for readability purposes) reduce the code in the master stored procedure

So i thought id performance test a UDF, I've come up with the following Fig.3

**Fig.3**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION TestFunction (@OrderId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN
  (
  -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
  SELECT 1 AS Total
    FROM (
      SELECT OrderLineItems.Id AS Id
        FROM OrderLineItems
        WHERE @OrderId = Order_Id) AS Sub
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 AS Total
          FROM NormalizedLineItems
          WHERE (Sub.Id = OrderLineItem_Id)
            AND (OutOfStock = 1)))
GO
```

All though the above compiles, I'm not really sure I'm on the right track, I'm having all sorts of problems trying to apply the above UDF to the original query.

I am seeking a concrete example of how to abstract Fig.2 from Fig.1 into a UDF so I can at least performance-test the solution to see if it's worthwhile.

Note: I do know user defined functions can be a performance nightmare, however I'm not even at a stage where I can test.

Comment: It might be the last choice using UDF to simplify your code in where clause. Use CTE or regular table for reusable data is a good practice. Or `EXEC` dynamic querys combinated by different pieces of sql statement strings.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answer, ill research the points you made, and test your code, gives me food for thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an order_ids table with only one column named order_id

```
Insert into order_ids
select order_id from 
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
        FROM (
          SELECT Id 
            FROM OrderLineItems 
            WHERE Orders.Id = Order_Id) AS Sub
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
              FROM NormalizedLineItems 
              WHERE (Sub.Id = OrderLineItem_Id)
                AND (OutOfStock = 1))))
```

Then you can simplify your Sql like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total
  FROM Orders 
  join order_ids
  on order_ids.order_id = Orders.order_id
 ...
```

If your reoccurring statement only in one query,
[Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) is the best choice:

```
with CTE_order_ids as
(select order_id from 
  FROM Orders 
  WHERE (NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
        FROM (
          SELECT Id 
            FROM OrderLineItems 
            WHERE Orders.Id = Order_Id) AS Sub
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
              FROM NormalizedLineItems 
              WHERE (Sub.Id = OrderLineItem_Id)
                AND (OutOfStock = 1))))
)
SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total
  FROM Orders 
  join CTE_order_ids 
  on order_ids.order_id = Orders.order_id
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this, ive tested it out, and it also gives me a good performance benifit